# Regular expression of equal length for the reversal of the language

Tags: regex, reverse, theory, regular-language, finite-automata

I'm studying CS Theory on my own and I've been trying to tackle a tough proof.

The original problem defined in formal terms here:

[image]

Basically, I have to prove that following: given some regular expression for a language, can you always have a regular expression of equal length for the reverse of that language.

I have no problems proving that regular languages are closed under reversal, but the length constraint makes it much more difficult. Please help me out if you can, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You only need to construct a regular expression for the reverse language given the original regular expression. Because regular expressions are defined recursively, you would only need to reverse the concatenation of the sub regular expressions, leaving others untouched. The lengths are obviously equal.

Example: `ab(c|d*e)` -> `(ed*|c)ba`

Answer (score 1):

We need to do induction over the structure of regular expressions. The outline being as follows, the details need to be filled in:

for a terminal w, w^R = w, and thus obviously |w| = |w^R|.

for a regular expression (w_1|w_2), with |w_1^R| = |w_1| and |w_2^R| = |w_2|, we have (w_1|w_2)^R = (w_1^R|w_2^R) and thus |(w_1|w_2)| = |(w_1|w_2)^R|

for a regular expression w* with |w| = |w^R|, we have w*^R = w^R*, and thus |w*| = |w*^R|

for a regular expression w_1w_2 with |w_1| = |w_1^R| and |w_2| = |w_2^R|, we have (w_1w_2)^R = w_2^Rw_1^R, and thus |w_1w_2| = |w_1| + |w_2| = |w_1^R| + |w_2^R| = |w_2^Rw_1^R|

What needs to be proven here still is that L(w*^R) = L(w^R*) and L^R(w_1w_2) = L(w_2^Rw_1^R).